# ExtJS Paging toolbar with an ability to select items count per page

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Im using ExtJS 4.2 [Ext.toolbar.Paging](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging) and I want to have an ability to select items count on a page, ie set `pageSize` of a store.

My solution is to extend existing Ext.toolbar.Paging, but maybe there is much easier solution? Or my solution can be improved?

Solution:

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.toolbar.Paging'
]);

Ext.define('Ext.lib.extensions.PortalPagingToolbar', {
    extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Paging',
    alias: 'widget.portalPagingToolbar',
    alternateClassName: 'Portal.PagingToolbar',

    /**
     * Objects per page default
     */
    objectsPerPageDefault: 25,

    /**
     * Objects per page text
     */
    objectsPerPageText: 'Objects per page:',

    /**
     * Gets the paging items in the toolbar
     * @private
     */
    getPagingItems: function () {
        var me = this;

        return [
            {
                itemId: 'first',
                tooltip: me.firstText,
                overflowText: me.firstText,
                iconCls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'tbar-page-first',
                disabled: true,
                handler: me.moveFirst,
                scope: me
            },
            {
                itemId: 'prev',
                tooltip: me.prevText,
                overflowText: me.prevText,
                iconCls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'tbar-page-prev',
                disabled: true,
                handler: me.movePrevious,
                scope: me
            },
            '-',
            me.beforePageText,
            {
                xtype: 'numberfield',
                itemId: 'inputItem',
                name: 'inputItem',
                cls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'tbar-page-number',
                allowDecimals: false,
                minValue: 1,
                hideTrigger: true,
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                keyNavEnabled: false,
                selectOnFocus: true,
                submitValue: false,
                // mark it as not a field so the form will not catch it when    getting fields
                isFormField: false,
                width: me.inputItemWidth,
                listeners: {
                    scope: me,
                    keydown: me.onPagingKeyDown,
                    blur: me.onPagingBlur
                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'tbtext',
                itemId: 'afterTextItem',
                text: Ext.String.format(me.afterPageText, 1)
            },
            '-',
            {
                itemId: 'next',
                tooltip: me.nextText,
                overflowText: me.nextText,
                iconCls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'tbar-page-next',
                disabled: true,
                handler: me.moveNext,
                scope: me
            },
            {
                itemId: 'last',
                tooltip: me.lastText,
                overflowText: me.lastText,
                iconCls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'tbar-page-last',
                disabled: true,
                handler: me.moveLast,
                scope: me
            },
            '-',
            {
                xtype: 'tbtext',
                itemId: 'objectsPerPageText',
                text: Ext.String.format(me.objectsPerPageText, 1)
            },
            {
                xtype: 'combo',
                isFormField: false,
                itemId: 'comboItemsCount',
                name: 'comboItemsCount',
                store: [
                    ['10', '10'],
                    ['25', '25'],
                    ['50', '50'],
                    ['100', '100'],
                    ['250', '250'],
                    ['500', '500'],
                    ['1000', '1000']
                ],
                width: 75,
                listeners: {
                    scope: me,
                    change: me.onItemsPerPageChange
                }
            },
            '-',
            {
                itemId: 'refresh',
                tooltip: me.refreshText,
                overflowText: me.refreshText,
                iconCls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'tbar-loading',
                handler: me.doRefresh,
                scope: me
            }
        ];
    },

    // @private
    onLoad: function () {
        var me = this,
            pageData,
            pageSize,
            currPage,
            pageCount,
            afterText,
            count,
            isEmpty;

        count = me.store.getCount();
        isEmpty = count === 0;
        if (!isEmpty) {
            pageData = me.getPageData();
            pageSize = pageData.pageSize ? pageData.pageSize : me.objectsPerPageDefault;
            currPage = pageData.currentPage;
            pageCount = pageData.pageCount;
            afterText = Ext.String.format(me.afterPageText, isNaN(pageCount) ? 1 : pageCount);
        } else {
            pageData = me.objectsPerPageDefault;
            currPage = 0;
            pageCount = 0;
            afterText = Ext.String.format(me.afterPageText, 0);
        }

        Ext.suspendLayouts();
        me.child('#afterTextItem').setText(afterText);
        me.child('#inputItem').setDisabled(isEmpty).setValue(currPage);
        me.child('#first').setDisabled(currPage === 1 || isEmpty);
        me.child('#prev').setDisabled(currPage === 1 || isEmpty);
        me.child('#next').setDisabled(currPage === pageCount || isEmpty);
        me.child('#last').setDisabled(currPage === pageCount || isEmpty);
        me.child('#comboItemsCount').setDisabled(isEmpty).setValue(pageSize);
        me.child('#refresh').enable();
        me.updateInfo();
        Ext.resumeLayouts(true);

        if (me.rendered) {
            me.fireEvent('change', me, pageData);
        }
    },

    // @private
    getPageData: function () {
        var store = this.store,
            totalCount = store.getTotalCount();

        return {
            total: totalCount,
            pageSize: store.pageSize,
            currentPage: store.currentPage,
            pageCount: Math.ceil(totalCount / store.pageSize),
            fromRecord: ((store.currentPage - 1) * store.pageSize) + 1,
            toRecord: Math.min(store.currentPage * store.pageSize, totalCount)

        };
    },

    //@private
    onItemsPerPageChange: function (combo, newValue) {
        var me = this;

        if(newValue) {
            me.store.pageSize = newValue;
            me.store.loadPage(1);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "to select items count on a page"? If you want to know how many items a page has, ask the store (`getTotalCount()`, `getPageSize()` and `currentPage` will be your friends). It has nothing to do with toolbars whatsoever.

Comment: I mean I want to select items count, displayed on a page (updated question title), ie set `pageSize` of a store.

Comment: You know, there's always a better solution. A couple of saved lines of  code, runs 1ms faster, etc. The only question is what's the price of the better solution. If your extension works fine then, IMO, it's not worth to optimize.

Comment: I agree, just I was wondering if great SO community could point on much easier solution or major issues with my solution. And even if no one provide an answer, than this example will be useful to someone who will be lookin for a similar problem.

Comment: The biggest "issue" with your code is that it duplicates a lot from the original `Ext.toolbar.Paging`. You could consider using [prependButtons](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging-cfg-prependButtons), or overriding `initComponent` to inject your custom inputs where required instead of duplicating the whole `getPagingItems` method. Also, what's the point in overriding `getPageData`? Just to add `pageSize`? Why if it's available from `this.store.pageSize` at all times? You see, all those tiny little things..